# Getting wrong labels from KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

Installed the KnpPaginatorBundle on a symfony 3 project for first time today, and getting strange bug. Instead of Previous and Next button, I get "« label_previous" ...... and "label_next »". I have done some experiments with adding languages to the `config.yml` before, but after reverting them today, I still don't get the right labels for the buttons.

[Picture of the pages navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meH4P.png)

and my config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
 
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en
 
framework:
   #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
       # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true
 
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
       - bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
       
    globals:
        brands: '@list_brands'
 
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'
 
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
 
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
 
#KNP
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig'     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template
```

The *twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig* file

```
{% if pageCount > 1 %}
    <ul class="pagination">

    {% if previous is defined %}
        <li>
            <a rel="prev" href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): previous})) }}">&laquo;&nbsp;{{ 'label_previous'|trans({}, 'KnpPaginatorBundle') }}</a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="disabled">
            <span>&laquo;&nbsp;{{ 'label_previous'|trans({}, 'KnpPaginatorBundle') }}</span>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if startPage > 1 %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): 1})) }}">1</a>
        </li>
        {% if startPage == 3 %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): 2})) }}">2</a>
            </li>
        {% elseif startPage != 2 %}
        <li class="disabled">
            <span>&hellip;</span>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    {% for page in pagesInRange %}
        {% if page != current %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="active">
                <span>{{ page }}</span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    {% if pageCount > endPage %}
        {% if pageCount > (endPage + 1) %}
            {% if pageCount > (endPage + 2) %}
                <li class="disabled">
                    <span>&hellip;</span>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): (pageCount - 1)})) }}">{{ pageCount -1 }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): pageCount})) }}">{{ pageCount }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if next is defined %}
        <li>
            <a rel="next" href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): next})) }}">{{ 'label_next'|trans({}, 'KnpPaginatorBundle') }}&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="disabled">
            <span>{{ 'label_next'|trans({}, 'KnpPaginatorBundle') }}&nbsp;&raquo;</span>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: how is the code of `KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig`

Comment: @leo_ap I dont understand your question.

Comment: knp_paginator uses templates files to render the template. look a the last 2 lines of your config.yml and you will see 2 files, one of then is the one I'm asking you to show us the code

Comment: Understood, I wasn't sure where are they till now, sorry, added now.

Comment: whats your default language (locale)?

Comment: How to check this?

Comment: if you didn't changed, its probably `en`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This template file `twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig` uses the `trans` twig filter to get the name of the label. You can see this, for example, in the part:

`<span>&laquo;&nbsp;{{ 'label_previous'|trans({}, 'KnpPaginatorBundle') }}</span>`

The `trans` filter (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#trans) tries to locate an configuration file of translations in a specific context. Your context is the KnpPaginatorBundle, so, it will search for a translation file inside this bundle. Look at it here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/tree/master/Resources/translations.

There are one translation file for every locale, but if your application default locale is one that is not in this list, it will not translate.

But, if your locale is `en` and it still doesn't work, you can make your own template and put the label manually.

Do this in 3 simple steps.

**1º:** Create a new file named `pagination.twig.html` (or something like that) under the `app/Resources/views` folder.

**2º:** Copy the code of the file `twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig` and paste in your new created file. Then, change the lines that refers to the `trans` filter. Example:

The line:
`<span>&laquo;&nbsp;{{ 'label_previous'|trans({}, 'KnpPaginatorBundle') }}</span>`

You should edit to:
`<span>&laquo;&nbsp; Previous</span>`

**3º:** In your `app/config/config.yml` change the file in the knp_paginator/template/pagination key. It should be something like this:

```
#KNP
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: 'pagination.html.twig'
        sortable: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template
```

Comment: I had just to uncomment this line, in my config after all: translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }